# Adding apple-mobile-web-app-capable stops SVG touches being recognised

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, ios8, mobile-safari

I'm trying to add touch functionality to an SVG.

I recognise the touch event using a jQuery like selector.
(I'm actually using angular JQLite -  angular.element()):

```
 .on("mousedown touch", function(event) {
```

On my desktop and in mobile Safari, there's no issue. The touches are recognised correctly. 
It also responds correctly when saved as a bookmark, but when I include:

```
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

in my header, and save to the home screen.. the touch piece doesn't respond.

I'm wondering whether anybody knows the root cause of this or has a a workaround?
I'm using Angular 1.2.27 and iOS 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For info, I worked around the issue by embedding an ng-click within the SVG itself.

This would tend to point to angulars JQLite implementation of click/moousedown/touchstart being the cause or possibly not supporting the same touch events as ng-click.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your css-file.

```
svg {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Now it should work.